# Allowing user to add option to the drop down list in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application have included a button called form Field. whenever user clicks on that button dropdownlist gets displayed in modal box that contains text, checkbox etc as option.

```
function Select_type(box) {
             var tp = document.getElementById('Type').value;
             switch (tp) {
                 case "Text":
                     {
                     var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                     editor.insertHtml('<input type="text" id="tx" />'); 
                 }
                     break;
                 case "Checkbox": 
                     { 
                         var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                         editor.insertHtml(' <input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" />');
                                        } 
                     break;
                 case "Radio": 
                     { 
                 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                 editor.insertHtml('<input type="radio" id="rd" name="rd" />');
                   }
                     break;
                 case "DropDown":
                     {
                         var ediotr = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                         ediotr.insertHtml('<select id="options"></select>');
                         dhtmlx.modalbox({
                             title: "Form Field Properties",
                             text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div ><label>Field Options:<input id='txt'></label><br></div><div><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='submit' value='Add' style='width: 86px' onclick='Add_type(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
                             width: "300px"
                         });
                     }

                     break;
                 case "Listbox": alert("Listbox");
                     break;
             }              
             dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
         }
```

When user selects drop down option a modal box appears that allows the user to add option to the drop down list

```
function Add_type(box) {
             var txt = $('#txt').val();
             if (txt.length > 0) {
                 $("#options").append("<option value='" + (txt.length - 1) + "'>" + txt + "</option>")
             }
         }
```

Textarea and button appears in modal box but it doesn't add the options that user has entered in textarea

Answer (score 1):

function Add_type() {

    
             var txt = $('#txt').val();

    
             if (txt.length > 0) {
        
                 var lBox = $('select[id$=options]');
        
                 $(lBox ).append("<option value=' " + (txt.length - 1) + " '>" + txt + "</option>")
             
    }
         
}

I tried like this, it was working

Comment: I tried the above code but still it doesn't work. I mean the options are not getting displayed in drop downlist

Comment: I tried like this, it was working
    <select id="options">
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" onclick="Add_type();" />

Comment: Have you tried it in CKEDITOR ya in textarea?
I want to display drop down list in CKEDITOR